# Class declarations and Class expressions in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm not clear about Class expressions and Class declarations. Please help me to understand for the different between them.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the difference between function declarations and function expressions? Same difference (except classes are never hoisted).

Comment: An example using [class expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66653378/2873538) to create an HOC (*function that receives a class and return a new class wrapping the original class*) in ReactJS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's relatively simple.

In "Class Expressions", the class object `NamedFoo` is being assigned to a variable named `Foo`, like so:

```
var Foo = class NamedFoo {
  constructor() {}
  whoIsThere() {
    return NamedFoo.name;
  }
}
```

In "Class Declarations", the class object `NamedFoo` is being declared solely by itself, like so:

```
class NamedFoo {
  constructor() {}
  whoIsThere() {
    return NamedFoo.name;
  }
}
```

The distinction here also being that when it's a "Class Declaration", you can reference the class by using `NamedFoo`, however, when it's a "Class Expression", you'll only be able to reference the class by the variable that it was assigned to, in this case `Foo`.

I hope that helps!

Comment: It might be worth clarifying that the variable assignment has nothing to do with the class expression itself. It's just one use case where a class expression may occur. As the name implies a class *expression* can be used wherever an expression is used. E.g. `foo(class {})`.

Comment: @FelixKling has a solid point, "class expressions" are indeed not bound to just variable assignments.

Comment: Any inclinations on benefits of one over the other and/or specific use-cases, or is is just personal preference. Personally, I prefer class declarations, but just like with functions I have found myself using both forms for different cases...

Comment: @CodeFinity. Doesn't seem to be any clear benefit of one over the other like there is with function declarations vs function expressions. Class declarations aren't hoisted and they do not become properties of the global object the way function declarations do. As such I am only using class declarations until i bump into a situation where a class expression is somehow a better fit.

Comment: @SteveCarey Sounds good. `class` is pretty clean looking, although for those coming from other languages, they may get thrown off b/c it's much different from traditional OOP.

Comment: @codeFinity. Yeah, at first brush its a little funny that they chose the keyword "class" when it's not technically a class. But if you treat it just like a class in another language then using "class" makes perfect sense, so I think it was the right choice. Class expression syntax just looks odd though. If there's not a clear advantage to using it I can't see why anyone would.

Comment: Hi @SteveCarey Here is an example using [class expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66653378/2873538) to create HOC (*function that receives a class and return a new class wrapping the original class*) in ReactJS.