# what is class extends React.component in React

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-functions, es6-class

In this link https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html
where explanation is of higher order component.The code is below has class extends React.component. What is this class keyword here?

```
function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      console.log('Current props: ', this.props);
      console.log('Previous props: ', prevProps);
    }
    render() {
      // Wraps the input component in a container, without mutating it. Good!
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create components using classes, the `class` here is a [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) which is being used to build a [class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

Comment: [Class declarations and Class expressions in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38004785/2873538)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an **unnamed** [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class).

```
return class extends React.Component {
```

The above code is creating an unnamed / anonymous class by extending `React.Component` class, hence, creating a new *React Component* which wraps (returns) the `WrappedComponent` passed to the function `logProps`.

**The syntax of class expression is:**

```js
const MyClass = class [className] [extends otherClassName] {
    // class body
};
```

where the name `className` (and also, `extends otherClassName`) is optional.

And, in your code in question, it is just **returning** the result instead of assigning it to a variable:

```
return class [className] [extends otherClassName] {
    // class body
};
```

Note that, there are **two** ways to create a [React Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), one is by writing a `function` and the other is by writing a `class`.

And, in JavaScript, [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) was introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (also knows as ES6).